# JSON-LD Frame : Expand on @type

Tags: json-ld

I want to use a json-ld frame to expand on types:

Document (or gist: https://gist.github.com/agustaf9/3c4884af3044b0a1508f7f0c6d4d15da):

```
{
  "@graph": [
    {
      "@id": "ex:Class1",
      "view:view": {
        "@id": "view:Class1View"
      },
      "view:preferredView": {
        "@id": "view:Class1View"
      }
    },
    {
      "@id": "exData:Class1-Instance1",
      "@type": [
        "ex:Class1",
        "ex:class2"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "@context": {
    "ex": "https://example.com/ontologies/ex#",
    "view": "http://www.example.com/ontologies/view#",
    "exData": "https://example.com/data/ex#"

  }
}
```

The desired result would be something like this:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "ex": "https://example.com/ontologies/ex#",
    "view": "http://www.example.com/ontologies/view#",
    "exData": "https://example.com/data/ex#"
  },
  "@id": "exData:Class1-Instance1",
  "@type": [
    "ex:Class1": {
        "view:view": [{
            "@id": "views:Class1View"
        }],
        "view:preferredView": {
            "@id": "views:Class1View"
        }
    },
    "ex:class2": {}
  ]
}
```

I have tried a frame like this:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "ex": "https://example.com/ontologies/ex#",
    "view": "http://www.example.com/ontologies/view#",
    "exData": "https://example.com/data/ex#"
  },
  "@id": "exData:Class1-Instance1",
  "@type": [{
      "view:view": [{
           
      }],
      "view:preferredView": {}
  }]
}
```

I understand that is not how `@type` is supposed to work, even with the desired result, but I am not sure how to better frame it to get class properties.
I also tried replacing `@type` with `rdf:type`, but that gives  a value of `null`. I have also tried using the `@exand` tag in the root of the frame (along with the `@id`) to hopefully expand, but that did not work either.